# What key do I need for this valve?

Tags: plumbing

This is the drain valve for the Megaflow immersion heater tank. What key do I need for it? It is about 7mm square, which is bigger than a radiator key. Also, which is this type of valve called?

[image: Valve]

Comment: how about a 7mm wrench?

Comment: That's so obvious I missed it!

Comment: @agentp if you post that as an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for an "outdoor spigot key" or a "sillcock key".  Googling those terms returns several options, including a 4-way "universal" chuck from Amazon, Lowe's, Home Depot, Ace Hardware and more.

Most options seem to be $5-10 USD.

Comment: If it measures exactly 7mm, then you'll want the 9/32" size. Otherwise get the 4-way cross type like computercarguy said and you won't buy the wrong size by mistake. http://a.co/9VosD5X

Answer (score -2):

A pair of pliers works great.   This looks like a gate valve, not a quarter turn valve.   So you might have to unscrew a couple turns to get it fully open.

Comment: Even when using locking pliers, you're likely to round off the corners, so pliers is not a good solution.  They will work, but you're likely to have to replace the whole valve, once those corners are gone.